# Android SQLite - Get ID

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to get the primary key (ID) created by the following insert:

```
public void insert (int FK_Vistoria, int CodIrregularidade, int FK_Equipamento, int FK_SubArea) throws SQLException {
    String sql = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO " + DATABASE_TABLE + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";
    SQLiteStatement statement = mDb.compileStatement(sql);
    mDb.beginTransaction();

    statement.bindLong(1, FK_Vistoria);
    statement.bindLong(2, FK_Equipamento);
    statement.bindLong(3, CodIrregularidade);
    statement.bindLong(4, FK_SubArea);

    statement.execute();

    mDb.setTransactionSuccessful();
    mDb.endTransaction();
}
```

I tried do get it by using this piece of code:

```
int idIrregularidade = mDb.insert(idVistoria, idCriterio, idEquipamento, idArea);
```

Could someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQLiteStatement.execute()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html#execute()) method return `void` instead of inserted row id.

Use [SQLiteStatement.executeInsert ()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html#executeInsert()) which return *the row ID of the last row inserted, if this insert is successful. -1 otherwise*

Change `insert` method as to get row ID on call of it:

```
public long insert (int FK_Vistoria,...){
   ....
   long insertedRowID= statement.executeInsert();
   ....
   return insertedRowID;
}
```